# deja-dup/duplicity: Backup Failed InvalidBackendURL

Tags: 18.04, backup, deja-dup, duplicity

I have launched a backup on Ubuntu 18.04 via the Déjà Dup Backup Tool and it fails with the following error:

```
Backup Failed InvalidBackendURL: missing // - relative paths not supported for scheme invalid: invalid://`
```

The version of `deja-dup` is 37.1-2:

```bsh
$ sudo apt list -a deja-dup
Listing... Done
deja-dup/bionic-updates 37.1-2fakesync1ubuntu0.1 amd64
deja-dup/bionic 37.1-2fakesync1 amd64
```

I have marked my home directory as a folder to save, and marked Trash, ~/miniconda3, and ~/Downloads to be ignored. I am saving the backup to an external hard disk.

I am also seeing these errors:

```bsh
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1555, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1541, in with_tempdir
    fn()
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1380, in main
    action = commandline.ProcessCommandLine(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/commandline.py", line 1135, in ProcessCommandLine
    backup, local_pathname = set_backend(args[0], args[1])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/commandline.py", line 1010, in set_backend
    globals.backend = backend.get_backend(bend)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 223, in get_backend
    obj = get_backend_object(url_string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 209, in get_backend_object
    return factory(pu)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/backends/giobackend.py", line 97, in __init__
    self.remote_file.make_directory_with_parents(None)
 Error: g-io-error-quark: Error creating directory /media/james/passport: Permission denied (14)
```

Below are the permissions of the disk where the backup is being performed:

```
$ ll /media/james/passport
total 100
drwxr-xr-x 4 james james 32768 Dec 31 1969 ./
drwxr-x---+ 3 root root 4096 May 29 10:59 ../
drwxr-xr-x 3 james james 32768 May 29 10:59 scw/
drwxr-xr-x 5 james james 32768 May 29 10:48 .Trash-1000/
```

Why I am getting the above errors, and/or how can I resolve? Thanks in advance for any suggestions.