# how to determine deja dup error source

Tags: 22.04, backup, deja-dup

I'm trying to restore a backup on Ubuntu 22.04 5.19.0-38-generic.

Did a backup of the home folder onto a HDD which is now supposed to be restored to the home folder after a reinstall.

```
    INFO 1
. Using temporary directory /tmp/duplicity-kokbuhzf-tempdir

INFO 1
. User error detail: Traceback (innermost last):
.   File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 92, in <module>
.     with_tempdir(main)
.   File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 75, in with_tempdir
.     fn()
.   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 1555, in main
.     action = commandline.ProcessCommandLine(sys.argv[1:])
.   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/commandline.py", line 1188, in ProcessCommandLine
.     args = parse_cmdline_options(cmdline_list)
.   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/commandline.py", line 802, in parse_cmdline_options
.     lpath, backend_url = args_to_path_backend(args[0], args[1])
.   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/commandline.py", line 1080, in args_to_path_backend
.     arg1_is_backend, arg2_is_backend = backend.is_backend_url(arg1), backend.is_backend_url(arg2)
.   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 170, in is_backend_url
.     pu = ParsedUrl(url_string)
.   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 344, in __init__
.     raise InvalidBackendURL(u"missing // - relative paths not supported "
.  duplicity.errors.InvalidBackendURL: missing // - relative paths not supported for scheme invalid: invalid://
.

ERROR 23 InvalidBackendURL
. InvalidBackendURL: missing // - relative paths not supported for scheme invalid: invalid://
```

How would you go on determine the error source, supposing its a filename

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Looks similar to this unaswered question https://askubuntu.com/q/1148939/243321

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: instead of restoring everything at once, restore different directories one by one (or in small batches) to see which file/directory causes the issue (and simply omit it). This worked for me. "Fun" fact: if I tried to restore a batch of six folders, the error message occured and restoration was interrupted, if I restored them one by one/in smaller batches (of two in my case) everything worked fine.

Also one author in a forum suggested to install python-oauth, so I installed the python3-oauth2client (Python3-oauthlib was already installed when the issue occurred), but I am not sure if this solved anything, so maybe not necessary.